# Aspx file and page inheritance

Tags: asp.net, html, page-lifecycle

I have a base page called let's say Login.aspx with Login.aspx.cs code behind.

Now...I would like to derive page from that page for several specyfic customers. Basically nothing changes in layout (aspx file), the only think is difference in handling Page_Load event. However when I access my derived login page LoginClientName.aspx no output is rendered - my aspx file contains only:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Page Language="c#" Inherits="StandardPages.Login"%>
<script runat="server">
    protected override void DoLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        TryGenericUsernameWithDivision(username, password);
    }
</script>
```

Is there any way to make use of base class aspx file, or I have to copy over StandardPages.Login aspx file HTML content into new page?

Thanks, Pawel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking for [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

Comment: Good point, but with a great deal of legacy old ASP code I have to deal with I have to time to redo it now :)

Comment: there is no code behind class right now. I only have LoginClientName.aspx with content that is provided in question.

Comment: Basically , using master page to put common aspx content and avoid page layout duplication won't take too much effort so I'm using that solution.